# Sending zipped files as attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, archiving

I have a rails application that creates a couple of csv file, zips them up and sends them to the client as an attachment(for download) using this line:

```
send_file t.path, :x_sendfile => true, :type => 'application/zip', :filename => "invited_friends_stats.zip"
```

When I view the zipped file created on the server, I'm able to use it, however, when I download the file through the application, it uncompresses into a `.zip.cpgz` file, while in turn compresses into a `zip` file which compresses into a `.zip.cpgz` file, etc, etc.

I then downloaded "The Unarchiver" app (on Mac OSX) and when I try and open the `.zip` file I get an error: `"the contents cannot be extracted with this program"`

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Encoding error, etc? Is there something I'm missing from the line above, or in my configuration that would fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You try to stream the ZIP file. Try adding `:disposition => 'attachment'` to force the browser to download the complete file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Content-Disposition response header with something like this

```
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{@filename}\""
```